# Vscode language server extension connection.onCompletion

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am creating a language server. Specifically, the issue is with completions. I'm returning a big list of completion items but whenever I test my language the completion provider simply will not suggest anything after I type a dot(.) when I'm expecting it to suggest, essentially, class members associated with the symbol left of said dot(.). Don't get me wrong, suggestions work until I type the dot(.) character and then it says, "No Suggestions".

Also, I'm trying to implement this server side and not client side.

EDIT:
Essentially, I'm assembling a big list and returning it.

```js
connection.onInitialize((params: node.InitializeParams) => {
    workspaceFolder = params.workspaceFolders![0].uri;
    const capabilities = params.capabilities;

    // Does the client support the `workspace/configuration` request?
    // If not, we fall back using global settings.
    hasConfigurationCapability = !!(
        capabilities.workspace && !!capabilities.workspace.configuration
    );
    hasWorkspaceFolderCapability = !!(
        capabilities.workspace && !!capabilities.workspace.workspaceFolders
    );
    hasDiagnosticRelatedInformationCapability = !!(
        capabilities.textDocument &&
        capabilities.textDocument.publishDiagnostics &&
        capabilities.textDocument.publishDiagnostics.relatedInformation
    );

    capabilities.workspace!.workspaceEdit!.documentChanges = true;

    const result: node.InitializeResult = {
        capabilities: {
            textDocumentSync: node.TextDocumentSyncKind.Incremental,
            colorProvider: true,
            hoverProvider: true,
            definitionProvider: true,
            typeDefinitionProvider: true,
            referencesProvider: true,
            documentHighlightProvider: true,
            documentSymbolProvider: true,
            workspaceSymbolProvider: true,
            
            // codeActionProvider: true,
            codeLensProvider: {
                resolveProvider: true,
                workDoneProgress: false
            },
            // Tell the client that this server supports code completion.
            completionProvider: {
                resolveProvider: true,
                workDoneProgress: false,
                triggerCharacters: ['.', '/'],
                allCommitCharacters: ['.']
            },
            signatureHelpProvider: {
                triggerCharacters: ['('],
                retriggerCharacters: [','],
                workDoneProgress: false
            },
            executeCommandProvider: {
                commands: ["compile"],
                workDoneProgress: false
            },
            semanticTokensProvider: {
                documentSelector: [{ scheme: 'file', language: 'agc' }],
                legend: {
                    tokenTypes: gTokenTypes,
                    tokenModifiers: gTokenModifiers
                },
                full: true,
                workDoneProgress: false
            }
        }
    };
    if (hasWorkspaceFolderCapability) {
        result.capabilities.workspace = {
            workspaceFolders: {
                supported: true
            }
        };
    }
    return result;
});
```

```js
// This handler provides the initial list of the completion items.
connection.onCompletion(
    async (params: node.TextDocumentPositionParams): Promise<node.CompletionItem[] | node.CompletionList | undefined> => {
        console.log("completion");
        let doc = documents.get(params.textDocument.uri);

        let list:node.CompletionList = node.CompletionList.create([], true);
        list.items = list.items.concat(comp.GetAGKKeywordCompletionItems(), comp.GetAGKCommandCompletionItems(), agkDocs.getALLCompletionItems());
        list.items.push(sense.GetCommentSnippetCompletionItem(doc, params.position));
        list.items.push(sense.GetCommentSnippetCompletionItem(doc, params.position, true));

        console.log("END completion");
        return list;
    }
);
```

Comment: You should show your completionProvider code.

Comment: Here's my code.